# How to set checkbox checked?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

So i created a custom listview adapter. Every Listview's item contains a checkbox. And i have a button to check or uncheck all checkboxes in ListViw. I try to do it so:

```
// buttons' click listener's code
for(int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {  // list is some ListView
    View item = adapter.getView(1, null, list);  // adapter is list's adapter
    CheckBox ch = ((CheckBox)item.findViewById(R.id.myCheckbox));
    ch.setChecked(true);                         
}
```

As you can see i try to set all checkboxes in ListView checked. This code is perfomed successfully, no exception. But checkboxes reman unchecked. Why?

Answer (score 1):

change :

```
View item = adapter.getView(1, null, list);
```

to :

```
View item = adapter.getView(i, null, list);
```